# Code Loops Infinitly

Tags: java, string

I am creating a game where a user has to guess a letter which is in the word, if they guess correctly it displays the letter in the word if they guess incorrectly, it subtracts a life. the problem is if they guess correctly, it prints out the word for infiniti.
Here is my code:

```
char words[] = new char[getRandomPirateWord().length()];
     char words2[] = new char[getRandomPirateWord().length()];
     for(int i = 0; i < getRandomPirateWord().length(); i++)
     {
         words[i] = getRandomPirateWord().charAt(i);
         words2[i] = (getRandomPirateWord().charAt(i)==' ')?' ':'*';
     }
     while(getGuessLeft()>0)
     {
         getLettersGuesed().add(letter);

         if (!randomPirateWord.contains(letter+""))
         {
         setGuessLeft(getGuessLeft() - 1);
         System.out.println("You lost a life, now have " + getGuessLeft());
         }

         for(int i1 = 0; i1 <getRandomPirateWord().length(); i1++)
         {
            if(words[i1] == letter)
            {
                  words2[i1] = letter;
            }
        }

        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < getRandomPirateWord().length(); i1++)
        {
            System.out.print(words2[i1]);
```

Comment: Where in the code does it print out the word?  What do you see when you step through the code in your debugger?

Comment: This is invalid java code... where is the rest?

Comment: Please post the code for getRandomPirateWord()  and also the rest of the code here

Comment: The System.out.print(words2[i1]); is where it prints out the word; stepping through the debugger hasn't helped me at all. For Example if the user guesses letter a for a word which is ********** the console keeps on writing: a********* a********* a********* a********* over and over.

Comment: are you sure you want to create new words all the time? your for-loops are looping a random-length instead of a length defined by a previous word. should this be so?

Comment: also the code where letter is inputted

Comment: No I want it to loop for the length of the word, I will see if I can sort that out now, thanks.

Comment: check also my answer. i believe i found the bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the while-loop never terminates. This depends on that if you guess a letter that is inside the word, the while-loop gets going because you NEVER change the value of the variable letter

```
while(getGuessLeft()>0) {
    getLettersGuesed().add(letter);
    if (!randomPirateWord.contains(letter+"")) {
        setGuessLeft(getGuessLeft() - 1);
        System.out.println("You lost a life, now have " + getGuessLeft());
    }
    for(int i1 = 0; i1 <getRandomPirateWord().length(); i1++) {
        if(words[i1] == letter) words2[i1] = letter;
    }
    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < getRandomPirateWord().length(); i1++){
        System.out.print(words2[i1]);
    }
}
```